# Send a flag instead a letter based in a json

Tags: json, sapui5

i don't know if i expleined i receive a json from an odata call and i send it to my table but one field have a X or is empty but instead of showing a X i want to show a flag like in ObjectListItem with a ObjectMarker type="Flagged" and just showing the flag

```
my table: (i delete some colums for this but my field that i'm interested is Sucursalescolacion and Sucursalesflag)
<Table  id="bSucursales"
                    inset="false"
                    items="{/}"
                    visible="false"
                    enableBusyIndicator="true">

                <columns>
                    <Column>
                        <Text text="{i18n>colSucursalesid}" />
                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Text text="{i18n>colSucursalesnombre}" />
                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Text text="{i18n>colSucursalesdircalle}" />
                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Text text="{i18n>colSucursalesdirnumero}" />
                    </Column>

                </columns>
                <items>
                    <ColumnListItem press="" type="Active">
                        <Text text="{Sucursalesdepto}"/>
                        <Text text="{Sucursalesfono1}"/>
                        <Text text="{Sucursalesfono2}"/>
                        <Text text="{Sucursalesactiva}"/>
                        <Text text="{Sucursaleshoraini}"/>
                        <Text text="{Sucursaleshorafin}"/>

                        <Text text="{Sucursalescolacion}"/>
                        <!-- <ObjectMarker type="Flagged"/> -->
                        <Text text="{Sucursalesflag}"/>
                    </ColumnListItem>
                </items>
            </Table>
```

my controller

```html
var bSucursales = this.byId("bSucursales");
         bSucursales.setVisible(true);
         oDataModel.read("/" + resultado2 +"?$filter=Maestropais eq '" + resultado + "'" + "and Maestrometodo eq '" + metodo + "'", {
          success: function(oData, response) {
           var oResults = oData.results;
                    oModel.setData(oResults);
                    bSucursales.setModel(oModel);
           },
           error: function(oError) { 
           
           }
         });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use expression binding:

```
<ObjectMarker type="{= ${Sucursalesflag} === 'X' : 'Flagged' : ''}" />
```

More info: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/5cff8d1c3fb84c5db7a00f2daca125af

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can choose to use a formatter as:

```html
<ObjectMarker type="{path: 'Sucursalesflag', formatter: '.formatSalesFlag'}"/>
```

Define formatter function in your controller:

```js
.
.
.
statusText: function (sSalesFlag) {
  if(sSalesFlag == 'X'){
        return 'Flagged';
      }
    else{ 
      return '';
    }
  }
}
```

You can write more complex custom formatters for different use-cases. [Learn more about customer formatters here](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/0f8626ed7b7542ffaa44601828db20de)